# Failed to use gdb for an executive file generated by cmake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, gdb, g++

To do debug for C++ codes with `cmake`, I have a trick to add the following lines before the `project (myProjectYY)` line of the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the root directory of the source code.

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O3 -Wall")
```

So, after `cmake` and `make`, I have obtained the executable file `mainYY`, and I can simply run `gdb mainYY` to do the debug as I should be able to see the source codes of `mainYY.cpp`.

I have 2 separated projects that were already `cmake` and `make` by the others, namely a simple project (i.e. `myProject1`) and a complicated project (i.e. `myProject2`). For `myProject1`, the above trick works for me, i.e. after I added the above 3 lines and re-do the `cmake` and `make` again to obtain `main1`, I can see the source code of `main1.cpp` by simply executing `l` in `gdb`.

But for `myProject2`, I do same, i.e. I added the above 3 lines and re-do the `cmake` and `make` again to obtain `main2`, but in `gdb` there is no source code for `main2.cpp`. That is, `gdb main2` firstly gave me `Reading symbols from main2...(no debugging symbols found)...done`. And then if I run `l` in `gdb`, I have `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command`.

What are the most probable reasons for such differences between `myProject1` and `myProject2`? How can I find out those probable reasons, and how can I do the fix such that I can debug for `myProject2`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mre], you've probably got a typo somewhere

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your `myProject2` is a complicated project. There could be `SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release ... FORCE )` somewhere. Check using `fgrep -R "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE"` and even better, remove every definition of this everywhere.

Use `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` instead.